# Need a word describing more frequently than monthly, other than semi monthly

Tags: time

We have business processes that happens periodically. These are labeled (in ascending frequency) as Quarterly, Monthly, Semi Monthly, Weekly, Semi Weekly, or Daily.

We also have a process that can happen 4, 6, or 8 times a month depending on other circumstances.

What's a nice, tight label for this frequency?

Comment: Perhaps *frequently*? (Seriously; you're looking for a single label, perhaps single word, describing a process that happens at a variable interval; I don't think you'll find one more specific than this.)

Comment: Agreed with @MattGutting, I think you can also coin a specific term for that and explain the definition somewhere, such as "Several Times in a Month" or **_STiM_**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a typical business jargon sort of term, I suggest **intra-monthly**.

**[intra-](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=intra%20definition)**

/ˈɪntrə/

prefix

(added to adjectives) on the inside; within.
"intramural"

Answer (score 1):

**intermittent**

/ɪntəˈmɪt(ə)nt/

adjective

occurring at irregular intervals; not continuous or steady.

[Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=intermittent%20definition)

**sporadic**

/spəˈradɪk/

adjective

occurring at irregular intervals or only in a few places; scattered or isolated.
"sporadic fighting broke out"

[Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=sporadic%20definition)

Answer (score 0):

The "processes" occur 4, 6 or 8 times a month, as you have mentioned. 
If they occur at irregular intervals, you can only say they happen **several times a month**, or **once or twice a week**.  That's the best I can come up with.

You might also use an adverb and say they happen frequently, very often, though that is subject to the listener's interpretation.